# Runtime error and wrong anwer Linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, c99

I am trying to solve [this spoj problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/SBE201P2/).

Here is my solution to the problem in C:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node{
    int data;
    struct node*next;
};
struct node* head=NULL;

void insertFront(int data)
{
    struct node*newnode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newnode->data=data;
    newnode->next=NULL;
    newnode->next=head;
    head=newnode;
}
int returnSize(){
    int cnt=0;
    struct node*temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        cnt++;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    return cnt;
}
void insertAt(int position,int data)
{
    struct node*newnode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newnode->data=data;
    newnode->next=NULL;
    if(head==NULL&&position>0)//marker1
    {
        head=newnode;
        return;
    }//marker2
    int cnt=returnSize();
    if(position>cnt)
    {
        struct node*var=head;
        while(var->next!=NULL)
        var=var->next;
        var->next=newnode;
        return;
    }
    int i;
    struct node*temp=head;
    if(position==0)
    {
    newnode->next=head;
    head=newnode;
    return;
    }
    else
    {
        for(i=0;i<position-1;i++)
        {
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        newnode->next=temp->next;
        temp->next=newnode;

    }   
}
void deleteAt(int position)
{
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        printf("empty");
        return;
    }
    int i,cnt=0;
    struct node*dummy=head;
        while(dummy->next!=NULL)
        {
            cnt++;
            dummy=dummy->next;
        }
        if(position>cnt)
        return;
    if(position==0)
    {
        struct node*temp=head;
        head=head->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    else
    {
        struct node*temp=head;
        for(i=0;i<position-1;i++)
        {
            if(temp!=NULL)
            temp=temp->next;
            else
            return;
        }
        temp->next=temp->next->next;
    }
}
void deleteFront()
{
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        printf("empty");
        return;
    }
    struct node*temp=head;
    head=head->next;
    free(temp);
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        printf("empty");
        return;
    }
}
void print()
{
    struct node*temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
int main()
{ 
char a;
do{

    char tmp;
    int b,c;
    scanf("%c",&a);
    if(a=='r')
    {
        deleteFront();

        print();
    }
    else if(a=='i')
    {
        scanf("%d",&b);
        scanf("%d",&c);
        insertAt(b,c);  
        print();
    }
    else if(a=='f')
    {
        scanf("%d",&b);
        insertFront(b);

        print();
    }
    else if(a=='d')
    {
        scanf("%d",&b);
        deleteAt(b);

        print();
    }
    scanf("%c",&tmp);
}while(a!='q');
    return 0;
}
```

If I remove the lines I marked as `marker` in the form of comment lines in the function `insertAt()`, I get a `segfault`. 
When I use them I get a wrong answer. I tested for many cases and I couldn't figure out where I was wrong.

Could someone help me out?

Comment: Why do you want to remove the lines? One suggestion would be to call insertFront when the condition (head==NULL and position > 0) is satisfied.

Comment: Anyway i did the same inside the condition scope right?

Comment: My question was why should those lines be removed? Also put up the test case for which you are receiving wrong results.

Comment: Initially i though the condition would be checked by position>cnt condition. but thats not true. And i don't know the test cases for which the program gets failing.

Comment: Err. I was missing a "\n" which got me a ton of unsuccessful submissions. It was accepted now. Thanks a lot @envy_intelligence for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I advise that you take a look at this question: [Do I cast the result of `malloc`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)... Suffice to say, the best pattern to follow as far as maintenance goes looks more like this:

```
foo *bar = malloc(sizeof *bar);
if (bar == NULL) {
    /* handle allocation error */
}
```

This way, if you ever have to change the type of `bar`, it's less likely that you'll forget to replace a typename somewhere; you'll be less likely to *create new bugs* during maintenance if you use this pattern.

---

```
newnode->next=NULL; /* <--- THIS IS UNNECESSARY */
newnode->next=head; /* <--- because this ends up being the value immediately after */
```

---

There are potential null pointer dereferences anywhere you've used `malloc` and neglected to check its return value. See the pattern above.

There's a potential null pointer dereference in `insertAt`, here: `temp=temp->next;` and here: `newnode->next=temp->next;`. The code between the markers guards your program from this null pointer reference when `head` is `NULL`... but that's not the only scenario where this null pointer dereference may be triggered.

There's a potential null pointer dereference in `deleteAt`, here: `temp->next=temp->next->next;`

---

You really should be checking the return value of `scanf` every time you use it.

---

For future reference, please fix your tabulation key so that we may help you more easily... It wouldn't surprise me if this is the reason only I have answered your question so far.